# AIX ACLs difference "permit" versus "specify"

Tags: permissions, filesystems, aix, acl, access-control

What's the difference in AIX ACLs with permit versus specify:

This is what the documentation says:

```
"The permit, deny, and specify keywords are defined as follows:
permit
    Grants the user or group the specified access to the file
deny
    Restricts the user or group from using the specified access to the file
specify
    Precisely defines the file access for the user or group 

If a user is denied a particular access by either a deny or a specify keyword, no other entry can override that access denial."
```

source: https://www.ibm.com/docs/el/aix/7.1?topic=system-aixc-access-control-list

Don't know if this is a very subtle english issue, and me not being native speaker.
Want to understand the difference.

Here an example:

```
attributes: SUID
base permissions:
    owner  (frank): rw-
    group (system): r-x
    others        : ---
extended permissions:
    enabled
        permit    rw-    u:dhs
        deny      r--    u:chas,    g:system
        specify   r--    u:john,    g:gateway, g:mail
        permit    rw-    g:account, g:finance
```

both "specify" and "permit" seem to work the same.

Edit:
Thank you user sllabres for the detailed answer.

Comment: _specify_ involves both _permit_ and _revoke_, e.g. you can specify `---` meaning no permissions at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.

From a quick check there is a difference who overlapping permissions are combined.

If you there is a user with read permission to a file and write permission via a group and both are 'permit' ACL, the user is able to read and write to the file. (the permissions are logically ORed together)

If there is a 'specify' ACL with e.g. only read permissions, only the read permissions are valid and the write permissions from e.g. a group are ignored.

If there are multiple 'specify' ACL they seem to be logically AND combined.

## Example

```
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# aclget test
*
* ACL_type   AIXC
*
attributes:
base permissions
    owner(root):  rw-
    group(system):  ---
    others:  -w-
extended permissions
    disabled
    permit   r--     u:testuser
```

With this permissions (disabled ACL) user 'testusr' can write to the file test (permissions from other) but not read.

```
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# echo "data" > test
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# cat test
cat: 0652-050 Cannot open test.
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
```

---

Enabling the ACL results in the ability to read the file, but 'testusr' cannot longer read to it due to the ACL having only specific read permissions now.

```
# aclget test
*
* ACL_type   AIXC
*
attributes:
base permissions
    owner(root):  rw-
    group(system):  ---
    others:  -w-
extended permissions
    enabled
    permit   r--     u:testuser
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# echo "data" > test
The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.
ksh: test: 0403-005 Cannot create the specified file.
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# cat test
data
```

---

Extending the ACL with the users group (staff) and write permissions for the group results in read permissions due to testuser being permitted to read in the ACL and write permissions via the staff group which testuser is member of. (logical ORed)

```
# aclget test
*
* ACL_type   AIXC
*
attributes: 
base permissions
    owner(root):  rw-
    group(system):  ---
    others:  -w-
extended permissions
    enabled
    permit   r--     u:testuser
    permit   -w-     g:staff
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# echo "data" > test
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# cat test
data
```

---

If read permissions for the user is change from 'permit' to 'specify' only the read permissions are valid, and the write permissions via the staff group not longer vaild.

```
# aclget test
*
* ACL_type   AIXC
*
attributes: 
base permissions
    owner(root):  rw-
    group(system):  ---
    others:  -w-
extended permissions
    enabled
    specify  r--     u:testuser
    permit   -w-     g:staff
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# echo "hi" > test
The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.
ksh: test: 0403-005 Cannot create the specified file.
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# cat test
data
```

---

If both ACL in this example u:testuser and g:staff are changed to 'specify' no read or write access is allowed (logical AND)

```
# aclget test
*
* ACL_type   AIXC
*
attributes: 
base permissions
    owner(root):  rw-
    group(system):  ---
    others:  -w-
extended permissions
    enabled
    specify  r--     u:testuser
    specify  -w-     g:staff
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# echo "data" > test
The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.
ksh: test: 0403-005 Cannot create the specified file.
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# cat test
cat: 0652-050 Cannot open test.
```

---

Changing the specify ACL g:staff permission to read and write only the read permission is granted and not read and write permissions as it would be with an allow ACL.

```
# aclget test
*
* ACL_type   AIXC
*
attributes: 
base permissions
    owner(root):  rw-
    group(system):  ---
    others:  -w-
extended permissions
    enabled
    specify  r--     u:testuser
    specify  rw-     g:staff
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# echo "hi" > test
The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.
ksh: test: 0403-005 Cannot create the specified file.
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
# cat test
data
testuser@testserver: /home/testuser >
```